# HP DV7 shows blank screen and does not start up, probably due to heat issues

Tags: cooling, hp-pavilion

I have a HP DV7, with an AMD Turion X2 ZM-85, purchased about 1.5 years ago.

Initially the laptop screen turned black. Only the screen – the machine was running. I could hear the fan spinning. Then I had to forcefully switch it off and keep it like that for about 15-20 minutes before I could restart it. I know I have to wait that long because I already tried turning it on before.

I took it to tech support and they said it was overheating. So I got the fan cleaned and added thermal grease too; it was all going well for a while. Then, I ran into the same issue again.

I also installed Coretemp and could observe that as soon as the temperature reached 60-64 °C, the laptop would shut down.

The issue went on and on... chill mats.. chill-pads with fans, but nothing really came in handy. Now the worst part is: The laptop doesn't switch on at all. When I try switching it on, it is runs for about five seconds and then shuts down again. (the fan spins)

I'm tired of this problem and honestly don't have the money right now for a new one. I'm reluctant to purchase any hardware without knowing what exactly the issue is here.

How can I restore my laptop back to the normal condition?

Comment: @Jitamaro I understand that you're offering your program as a possible solution but the bulk of your 'answer' is a narrative of things you've tried in your own situation, but it is vague and the way it is written, it is not very easy to understand what you mean.  Converted to comment as to allow the post to remain in some form, rather than deleting outright...  Perhaps if you would improve your readability and clear up some vague points, I/another mod will consider undeleting. Explain *more* about what your script/program could do for the OP, etc and make it clearer what helped and didn't help

Comment: @Jitamaro no, a different username wouldn't change anything.  If you really want to talk about it more, raise a post on Meta Super User.

Comment: sure, @Jitamaro, feel free to talk about it. But keep it to the point and have a simple question.  Explain the situation from your perspective. That way, you can get input from the rest of the community. Not just myself.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the laptop on "Power Saver" mode all of the time (vs. "HP recommended", and definitely not "High Performance") will give you some extra time before you need to get it repaired(again, and I feel your pain).

I have a laptop of the same series, and it does the same thing.  After a round at a PC repair place, it's able to hold its own using "HP Recommended" (with a chill mat) but still won't do "High Performance".

Comment: Thanks Jonsca! What exactly wass the propblem ? Was it a GPU issue or was it the CPU ?

Comment: @Superuzer I believe that it was something to do with the fan control, but it still wasn't 100% after it came back.